# jQuery UI Position wrong position on first load and correct on second reload

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery position UI plugin for positioning helper icons on the web page. This is my code responsible for the position:

```
    if ( $(element_selector).length !== 0 && $(title_class_selector).length !== 0  ) {

    $(title_class_selector).position({
    my: "center",
    at: cornerPosition,
    offset:"<?php echo $x_coordinates_foradjustment;?> <?php echo $y_coordinates_foradjustment;?>",
    of: $(element_selector)

    });

    }
```

Where cornerPosition has the following possible values:

```
left top
right top
left bottom
right bottom
```

It works pretty well until I encounter a problem for a specific div where I would like to append the icons. At first loading, the position is wrong (instead of left bottom it goes to left top) and the other one instead of right top, it goes to right bottom.

These are the affected element_selectors with their correct and wrong positions:

```
#wpv-featured-news-slider .span4:first-child .thumbnail
Correct position: Left bottom
Actual position on first loading of webpage: Left top

#wpv-featured-news-slider
Correct position: Right top
Actual position on first loading of webpage: Right bottom
```

What is strange is that when I refresh the page(reloading the page), it now goes to their correct positions!
Is this something wrong with the cache or the selectors? Is there a way to add some checks on this? I do not like to change the element_selectors to correct this problem.

This positioning system has been widely implemented in our different websites and this is the only occasion where I'm seeing this problem (all works OK with the rest). This could be a highly isolated case. I search for any related problems but could not find one. Any tips and suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered any issues with images? Sometime non cached images w/o specified height/width can cause position issues. Try https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded and see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Fatmuemoo I will check on this..Cheers.

Comment: I am having the same problem and this is not the solution. My images are loaded from cache  and if I put a timeout on the positioning of many seconds it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI uses [collision detection](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) and where a collision is found it will place the positioned item in a different position. The default value where not specified (as in your case) is flip, so it will flip the element to the opposite side of the target (as you describe).

Try changing the collision to "none".

I was having the same problem weirdly only affecting the page on initial load but OK on subsequent loads.